# ListView in Fragment in ViewPager in ScrollView for android >=2.3

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

Is it possible to do it?

[image: Here a little mockup to describe what I'd like to implement]

The main point are:

- A Complex header out of the listView but that must scroll
- A ListView whose scroll is handled by the far ScrollView parent.
- The ListView must have recyling, so the linearLayout cannot be a solution

Thanks

Comment: so the ListView is actually inside the ViewPager ?? So in each page there's a different ListView ?

Comment: Yes the listView is inside the fragment that was added by the ViewPager. In each page there is anything possible, sometimes a ListView

Comment: Did you find a proper solution to this? I am also trying to do exact same thing but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

to directly answer the question:

> Is it possible to do it?

Yes it is. You can see [this example here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baseapp.eyeem) in the Albums and Profiles sections. But it's not simple, nor straight forward.

There're two issues in adding a ListView inside a ScrollView (you can research that on your own) that is TouchEvents get mixed up because it doesn't know which `View` will consume the touch and the system don't know how to layout a infinite sized View inside another infinite sidez View.

Because it's it's not simple nor straight forward to implement, there several possible implementations and all of them is A LOT of code and A LOT of testing. I'll point you to a open source example and you can go from there:

https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is enclosing ListView inside ScrollView. The steps given below describe how to enclose *any* vertically scrollable view into another vertically scrollable view.

Step 1

Write a method which determines wheather a View can be scrolled vertically and place the method inside a common utility class as follows. This method is taken from ViewPager.java and modified to find whether a View can vertically scrollable.

```
public static boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dy, int x, int y) {
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) v;
        final int scrollX = v.getScrollX();
        final int scrollY = v.getScrollY();
        final int count = group.getChildCount();
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (x + scrollX >= child.getLeft()
                    && x + scrollX < child.getRight()
                    && y + scrollY >= child.getTop()
                    && y + scrollY < child.getBottom()
                    && canScroll(child, true, dy,
                            x + scrollX - child.getLeft(), y + scrollY
                                    - child.getTop())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return checkV && ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(v, -dy);
}
```

Step 2

Subclass the enclosing vertically scrollable view, it may be ScrollView or ListView(In your case it is `ScrollView`), or the like and override the onInterceptTouchEvent() method as follows.

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    float dy = y - mLastMotionY;
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mLastMotionY = y;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (Util.canScroll(this, false, (int) dy, (int) x, (int) y)) {
            mLastMotionY = y;
            return false;
        }
        break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Step 3

Subclass the enclosed vertically scrollable view, it may be GridView or ListView or the like(In your case `ListView`) and override the onMeasure() method as follows. No need to override this method in ScrollView. Its default implementation behaves in the right way.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        int height = getLayoutParams().height;
        if (height > 0)
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
    }
}
```

Step 4

Finally create an xml layout file and use the ScrollView and ListView that you subclassed and you **must hard code the `layout_height`**. If you are creating the view hierarchy through java code, then hard code the height by `LayoutParams`. This hard coding is not necessary if you use your own measuring strategy rather than one specified in step 3.

For further details please view this post [ScrollInsideScroll](http://durgadasss.blogspot.in/2014/10/scroll-inside-scrollthis-project-shows.html), download the project and examine the code.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get recycling `ListView` if you do not write it yourself. If you want to use the solution for nested fragments (as on image) try [this](http://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/doing-it-right-vertical-scrollview-with-viewpager-and-listview/).